# Is there a way to remove the colour black from a random colour generator?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random, colors, generator

In the game I am making there is a random enemy spawner that creates clones of the enemy sprite in different colour variations which is what I want it to do but any that come out black just make the game look bugged and untidy.

Is there any way to stop the randomizer from choosing black?

[How the car looks:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeXOH.jpg)

Here is the code for the generator:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class enemyscript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject enemy;

    private GameObject newEnemy;
    private SpriteRenderer rend;
    private int randomSpawnZone;
    private float randomXposition, randomYposition;
    private Vector3 spawnPosition;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        InvokeRepeating("SpawnNewEnemy", 0f, 5f);
    }

    private void SpawnNewEnemy()
    {
        randomSpawnZone = Random.Range(0, 2);
        
            switch (randomSpawnZone)
        {
            case 0:
                randomXposition = Random.Range(-16, -16);
                randomYposition = Random.Range(113, 113);
                break;
                case 1:
                randomXposition = Random.Range(3, 3);
                randomYposition = Random.Range(113, 113);
                break;
                
        }

        spawnPosition = new Vector3(randomXposition, randomYposition, 0f);
        newEnemy = Instantiate(enemy,spawnPosition,Quaternion.identity);
        rend = newEnemy.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        rend.color = new Color(Random.Range(0,2), Random.Range(0, 2), Random.Range(0, 2), 1f);
    }

    

}
```

The only thing I have tried is changing the "random.range(0,2)" numbers

Comment: Don't allow 0,0,0 as a choice of colour?

Comment: Just tested this code: rend.color = Random.ColorHSV(0f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 0.5f, 1f); and it seemed to work well! If anyone else has this issue try this

Comment: Nice solution, you should add this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested this code: rend.color = Random.ColorHSV(0f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 0.5f, 1f); and it seemed to work well! If anyone else has this issue try this